# Is it more common to refer to subplots as a "frame" or a "panel"?

Tags: publications, writing-style, graphics

In scientific publications, when referring to a figure with multiple plots, often labeled using (a), (b), etc., is it more common to refer to each subplot as a "frame" or a "panel"?  Are both correct terms? Is one more correct or commonly used than the other?

Comment: Sounds entirely a stylistic choice to me. Just be consistent within a paper.

Comment: This was my first thought but I wanted additional input.  After I finished writing my dissertation, everyone reviewing it has used "panel" when referencing a subplot.  I used "frame" throughout.  I am not sure if this difference was from my inexperience.  I do not want to change it throughout the entire document.

Comment: At the worst, that's what "Find and Replace All" is for :-)

Comment: Are you sure words such as "frame" or "panel" are used *in* papers, rather than on a meta-level, by typesetters? I have heard the word "panel", but only ever with respect to typography and page layout.

Comment: Here are some "panel" examples: 10.1128/JB.186.18.5973-5977.2004, 10.1021/ct900653p, 10.1016/j.bpj.2013.05.021, 10.1128/JB.01200-09, 10.1103/PhysRevLett.99.038104, 10.3390/nano5010246

Comment: I am having a hard time finding "frame" examples.  Perhaps it is best to avoid either but in situations where it is necessary to use "panel".

Comment: Have you ever seen "subplot" in the same context?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't recall having seen the word *frame* or *panel* used to refer to a subplot. More commonly:

In the text, e.g.,

> Figure 1(a) shows [...]; figure 1(b), instead, shows [...].

In the caption, e.g.,

> Figure 1. Comparison among blah blah: (a) function f [...]; (b) function g [...]

Comment: I've never used _frame_ or _panel_ either, but it could easily be a style variation between disciplines. See if any of the major professional societies in your field have a style guide, or see if the major journals have one. You might find an answer there.

Comment: I list a selection of example publications above which use *panel* but in my quick search, I could not find *frame* examples.  The use of *panel* is rare which leads me to think it best to avoid its use if possible in favor of the options provided here.

Comment: @stvn66 looking at some of the examples you provided, it might be that the authors chose to use the word "panel" because of the specific close-packed arrangement of the sub-figures, and of their type -- mostly photographs.